# <br> tag isnot not working while appending in li

Tags: jquery, cordova

While appending li `<br >` tag isn't working properly. The [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbdR7/5/) is working properly on chrome, IE8. But if we tried it on `webview` its not working.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with <br />, you may need to escape the slash ie <br \/>, this is \ / not V

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add an `<br>` just to add spacing. Try using CSS or something similar to add padding where needed.

**Current Markup**

```
<textarea cols=25 rows=10></textarea>
<div id="save">save</div>

<ul id="notes">
    <li>n<br/><br/>555</li>
</ul>
```

**Suggested**

```
<textarea cols=25 rows=10></textarea>
<div id="save">save</div>

<ul id="notes">
    <li>n<span>555</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#notes span {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 5px 0;
}
```

What you're doing is overkill with your js and bad in terms of the what the br/break is for.